# If we sum 2 Convergent Series, will their sum be also Convergent? Why or why not?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I would like to know in general if 2 convergent sequences, when summed together, also converge or that can be applied to specific cases.

If both series are convergent then
$$\sum_{n=0}^n An +  \sum_{n=0}^n Bn =$$
is the series of their sum convergent as well?
$$\sum_{n=0}^n An + Bn$$

If this doesn't hold for the general case, does it hold for this? :

$$\sum_{n=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n3}{2^n} + \sum_{n=0}^n \frac{1}{2^n} $$
Seperately, I've shown that these 2 are convergent. Can I simply make the claim that if these 2 are convergent, then this is convergent as well?:

$$\sum_{n=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n3}{2^n} +  \frac{1}{2^n} $$

If not, could you suggest another way to show convergence of the last series?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. You can add two convergent series and get the convergent series of their sum.

Comment: This is absolutely standard.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look on why this is the case. Define $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n Ak$ and $bn = \sum_{k=0}^n Bk$ We know from Analysis, that if two sequences converge, then their sum converges. So it holds that, if $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge, then $c_n = a_n+b_n  = \sum_{k=0}^n Ak + \sum_{k=0}^n Bk = \sum_{k=0}^n Ak+Bk$ converges too.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!